# How to close file in awk while generating a list of?

Tags: bash, text, awk

Guys I'm trying to find a way to don't have the awk error "too many open file" . Here's my situation:

INPUT : ASCII file, lot of line, with this scheme:

```
NODE_212_lenght.._1
NODE_212_lenght.._2
NODE_213_lenght.._1
NODE_213_lenght.._2
```

In order to split this file with every record with the same NODE number, I've used this one-liner awk command

```
awk -F "_" '{print >("orfs_for_node_" $2 "")}' <file
```

With a file composed by lots of lines, this command keeps sayin "too many open files" . I've tried also by splitting by 2k lines, same. 
I can't actually go under 2k lines, because the input one is a huge file.

I know awk could *close* a file after doing something inside, but I don't know actually how to do that. I've tried adding

```
awk -F "_" '{print >("orfs_for_node_" $2 ""); close(orfs_for_node_*)}' <file
```

but this will make no output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you switch to GNU awk that'll handle it for you. Otherwise this is the right syntax if your input file has all the lines for each $2 value grouped together:

```
awk -F '_' '{out="orfs_for_node_"$2} out!=prev{close(prev)} {print > out; prev=out}' file
```

otherwise you need to use `>>` instead of `>`:

```
awk -F '_' '{out="orfs_for_node_"$2} out!=prev{close(prev)} {print >> out; prev=out}' file
```

Note that in that second case you'd need to empty any pre-existing "out" files (e.g. from a previous run) before running it since it'll always append to the output files.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, you are looking for the right moment to `close` the file. For your example input content, you can do :

```
awk -F "_" 'BEGIN{prefix="orfs_for_node_"} 
NR>1&&$2!=last{close(prefix""last)}{last=$2;print >(prefix$2)}' inputFile
```

It checks the `$2` if it changed, then close the file with last `$2`. This assumes that the lines in your file are sorted by `$2`

If it is not sorted by `$2` use `>>`