# AWK taking very long to process file

Tags: awk

I have a large file with about 6 million records. I need to chunk this file into smaller files based on the first 17 chars. So records where the first 17 chars are same will be grouped into a file with the same name

The command I use for this is :

```
awk -v  FIELDWIDTHS="17"  '{print > $1".txt"}' $file_name
```

The problem is that this is painfully slow. For a file with 800K records it took about an hour to complete.

sample input would be :-

```
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA75838458
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA48234283
BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB34723643
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA64734987
BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB18741274
CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC38123922
```

Is there a faster solution to this problem?

I read that perl can also be used to split files but I couldnt find an option like fieldwidths in perl..

any help will be greatly appreciated

uname : Linux

bash-4.1$ ulimit -n
1024

Comment: If all records have unique prefixes I don't think any improvement would have a considerable effect on the performance

Comment: How many unique prefixes are there? It may be faster (counter intuitively) to sort the file based on the prefix first so that each prefix file is written to all at once. You may also be running into performance issues based on the sheer number of files...

Comment: How many files does your script generate? Add output of `ulimit -n` and name of your OS to your question.

Comment: @dawg  we expect about 5-6 records to have the share the same prefix..   so an 800K record file generated about 12000 smaller files

Comment: @Cyrus : added the output of uname and ulimit to the question above.

Comment: This might help: [How to close file in awk while generating a list of?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51209508/3776858)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sort file |
awk '{out=substr($0,1,17)".txt"} out != prev{close(prev); prev=out} {print > out}'
```

Performance improvements included:

1. By not referring to any field it lets awk not do field splitting
2. By sorting first and changing output file names only when the key part of the input changes, it lets awk only use 1 output file at a time instead of having to manage opening/closing potentially thousands of output files

And it's portable to all awks since it's not using gawk-specific extension like FIELDWIDTHS.

If the lines in each output file have to retain their original relative order after sorting then it'd be something like this (assuming no white space in the input just like in the example you provided):

```
awk '{print substr($0,1,17)".txt", NR, $0}' file |
sort -k1,1 -k2,2n |
awk '$1 != prev{close(prev); prev=$1} {print $3 > $1}'
```

After borrowing @dawg's script (`perl -le 'for (1..120000) {print map { (q(A)..q(Z))[rand(26)] } 1 .. 17} ' | awk '{for (i=1; i<6; i++) printf ("%s%05i\n", $0, i)}' | awk 'BEGIN{srand();} {printf "%06d %s\n", rand()*1000000, $0;}'| sort -n | cut -c8- > /tmp/test/file` - thanks!) to generate the same type of sample input file he has, here's the timings for the above:

```
$ time sort ../file | awk '{out=substr($0,1,17)".txt"} out != prev{close(prev); prev=out} {print > out}'

real    0m45.709s
user    0m15.124s
sys     0m34.090s

$ time awk '{print substr($0,1,17)".txt", NR, $0}' ../file | sort -k1,1 -k2,2n | awk '$1 != prev{close(prev); prev=$1} {print $3 > $1}'

real    0m49.190s
user    0m11.170s
sys     0m34.046s
```

and for @dawg's for comparison running on the same machine as the above with the same input ... I killed it after it had been running for 14+ minutes:

```
$ time awk -v  FIELDWIDTHS="17"  '{of=$1 ".txt"; if (of in seen){ print >>of } else {print >of; seen[of]; } close(of);}' ../file

real    14m23.473s
user    0m7.328s
sys     1m0.296s
```

Answer (score 1):

I created a test file of this form:

```
% head file
SXXYTTLDCNKRTDIHE00004
QAMKKMCOUHJFSGFFA00001
XGHCCGLVASMIUMVHS00002
MICMHWQSJOKDVGJEO00005
AIDKSTWRVGNMQWCMQ00001
OZQDJAXYWTLXSKAUS00003
XBAUOLWLFVVQSBKKC00005
ULRVFNKZIOWBUGGVL00004
NIXDTLKKNBSUMITOA00003
WVEEALFWNCNLWRAYR00001
% wc -l file
  600000 file
```

ie, 120,000 different 17 letter prefixes to with `01 - 05` appended in random order.

If you want a version for yourself, here is that test script:

```
perl -le 'for (1..120000) {print map { (q(A)..q(Z))[rand(26)] } 1 .. 17} ' | awk '{for (i=1; i<6; i++) printf ("%s%05i\n", $0, i)}' | awk 'BEGIN{srand();} {printf "%06d %s\n", rand()*1000000, $0;}'| sort -n | cut -c8- > /tmp/test/file
```

If I run this:

```
% time awk -v  FIELDWIDTHS="17"  '{print > $1".txt"}' file
```

Well I gave up after about 15 minutes.

You can do this instead:

```
% time awk -v  FIELDWIDTHS="17"  '{of=$1 ".txt"; if (of in seen){ print >>of } else {print >of; seen[of]; } close(of);}' file
```

You asked about Perl, and here is a similar program in Perl that is quite fast:

```
perl -lne '$p=unpack("A17", $_); if ($seen{$p}) { open(fh, ">>", "$p.txt"); print fh $_;} else { open(fh, ">", "$p.txt"); $seen{$p}++; }close fh' file
```

Here is a little script that compares Ed's awk to these:

```
#!/bin/bash

# run this in a clean directory Luke!

perl -le 'for (1..12000) {print map { (q(A)..q(Z))[rand(26)] } 1 .. 17} ' 
| awk '{for (i=1; i<6; i++) printf ("%s%05i\n", $0, i)}' 
| awk 'BEGIN{srand();} {printf "%06d %s\n", rand()*1000000, $0;}'
| sort -n 
| cut -c8- > file.txt

wc -l file.txt

#awk -v  FIELDWIDTHS="17"  '{cnt[$1]++} END{for (e in cnt) print e, cnt[e]}' file
echo "abd awk"
time awk -v  FIELDWIDTHS="17"  '{of=$1 ".txt"; if (of in seen){ print >>of } else {print >of; seen[of]; } close(of);}' file.txt

echo "abd Perl"
time perl -lne '$p=unpack("A17", $_); if ($seen{$p}) { open(fh, ">>", "$p.txt"); print fh $_;} else { open(fh, ">", "$p.txt"); $seen{$p}++; }close fh' file.txt

echo "Ed 1"
time sort file.txt |
awk '{out=substr($0,1,17)".txt"} out != prev{close(prev); prev=out} {print > out}'

echo "Ed 2"
time sort file.txt | awk '{out=substr($0,1,17)".txt"} out != prev{close(prev); prev=out} {print > out}'

echo "Ed 3"
time awk '{print substr($0,1,17)".txt", NR, $0}' file.txt | sort -k1,1 -k2,2n | awk '$1 != prev{close(prev); prev=$1} {print $3 > $1}'
```

Which prints:

```
   60000 file.txt
abd awk

real    0m3.058s
user    0m0.329s
sys 0m2.658s
abd Perl

real    0m3.091s
user    0m0.332s
sys 0m2.600s
Ed 1

real    0m1.158s
user    0m0.174s
sys 0m0.992s
Ed 2

real    0m1.069s
user    0m0.175s
sys 0m0.932s
Ed 3

real    0m1.174s
user    0m0.275s
sys 0m0.946s
```

Comment: Would you mind sharing the script you wrote to create the test input file (or testing the 2 scripts in my answer against your input and posting the result)? I'm assuming you're doing 3rd-run timing to remove any cacheing impact.

Comment: It is not my prettiest ;-). but I will add to the answer.

Comment: Luckily "pretty" isn't a target goal for throwaway code to generate a temp file, especially if it saves the rest of us the time of coming up with one for ourselves :-). Thanks!

Comment: Would you mind testing the timing for both of my scripts on your box? I wanted to post the timing for both of mine plus yours for a comparison on the same box with the same input, but on my laptop yours has been running for a few minutes already so I'm losing the will to try it more times to avoid cacheing issues.

Comment: Done. Yours are faster ;-) Note on my machine: It is a 16 core Mac Pro with 6x SSDs in a RAID 0. Not necessarily representative.

Comment: Ed 1 and Ed 2 in your timing output are the same script btw, one just has a line break after the first pipe while the other doesn't.